# Open SQL Server .mdf and .ldf files from recovery

Tags: sql-server, recovery, data-recovery

Recently I had a problem in a remote server which contains an small SQL Server running on.

I used [PhotoRec 7.0](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) for recovering all files including the files mdf and ldf but now I don't have any relationship between names and files. See example attached below:

[image: example files]

I couldn't attach mdf files on SQL Server Studio as there are no ldf files with the same name in the same folder.

I've used a third party tool for opening mdf files, and I'm able to see the contents on that files, but there were no luck for inspecting ldf.

Any ideas for relation mdf files with their respective ldf? Or a way for omitting the ldf file in order to import mdf file in SQL Server Studio?

Comment: You should backup database and store those backups, do not touch .mdf and .ldf files. Try start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/backup-overview-sql-server

Comment: Next step after this disaster recovery is to setup a real backup scenario. Backing up files are possibly inconsistent.

Comment: @MikhailLobanov You're all right. I tought backups were already set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the sequence of steps and you must be aware that,[this database may not be transactionally consistent.](http://sqlmag.com/blog/recovering-database-missing-transaction-log)

**Below are steps on how to get your db back online**

1.Create a database with same name (let's say newdb  )
2.Shut down the server
3.Replace newdb mdf ,ldf files with your oldones(olddb) and try to start sql server
4.Your newdb won't start and may* go into suspect state
5.If this is the case,try setting the database to emergency and set to singleuser  like below

```
alter database dbname set SET EMERGENCY;
alter database dbname  SET SINGLE_USER
```

6.now try running DBCC checkDB

```
DBCC CHECKDB (N'dbname', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS;
```

99% of issues will be fixed by DBCC and if so you are in luck..

Now trying setting the DB online and multi user

*There might be a chance,that your database is cleanly shutdown(no active transactions),if this is the case, you can try running below command ,prior to above steps.SQL will create a new log file for you

```
Create database dbname 
    On 
    (   
    Filename= 'path where you copied files'   
    )
    For attach;
```

**References:**
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-emergency-mode-repair-the-very-very-last-resort/
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/corruption-last-resorts-that-people-try-first/

Comment: Thank you!! Database was rescued almost 100% following your reference

Comment: @AlexDeiwor:using which option 1 or 2

Comment: in my case was the first one. @TheGameiswar